# Verifying the answer for a question on Riemann integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have given below a question and answer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I understand how the contribution of intervals containing points of for $1/n≥ϵ/2$  has a contribution to $U(P,f)$ that is less than ϵ/2. But I don't understand how the contribution from the rest of the sub intervals are made to be less than $ϵ/2$. Are there any gaps between these disjoint intervals or is the union of the disjoint intervals equal to $[ϵ/2,1]$? Would appreciate some clarifications. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that $f(x)<\epsilon/2$ on all the other intervals. So you don't need a perfect estimate on their combined length; the sum of their lengths being less than $1$ is all you need.

Comment: I guess another point is that, if you really want a partition of the interval and you're worried that there may be gaps between the chosen neighbourhoods of $1/n$, note that $f$ is zero on these gaps, so you can just throw them in (there are finitely many of them)

Comment: @MTurgeon Indeed. But if you don't rely too heavily on that point, you immediately obtain the Riemann integrability of *any* function $f\ge0$ so that, for each $\epsilon>0$, $f(x)\ge\epsilon$ for only finitely many $x$. For example: $f(x)=0$ if $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$, $f(p/q)=1/q$ if $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$. (I forget whose name is associated with that one. Dedekind?)

Comment: Good point. But it was my inderstanding that the OP was worried about these gaps, so I thought I would mention it.

Comment: @MTurgeon How is f zero in these gaps?

Comment: @user81883 You are between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks I get it now. There is no need of considering the interval [0,ϵ/2] then.

Comment: @MTurgeon Thanks I can't believe I was careless to miss that thanks alot!

Comment: @MTurgeon and it's good that you did (one of the two upvotes on your comment was mine).

Answer (score 0):

You take $N$ intervals whose total length is $\epsilon /2$ together with one interval $[0,\epsilon/2]$ whose length is $\epsilon/2$. On these intervals the function is bounded by $1$ hence they contribute $\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$ to the upper sum. On the rest of the interval (the gaps) the function is 0, hence whatever is the length of the other intervals they do not contribute to the upper sum.

Comment: So that means the gaps contain only irrationals? by a gap do you mean and interval? If so there can't be only irrationals in them right? correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: No, it is not a matter of rational/irrationals... Have you understood how you can take the $N$ intervals around the points $1,1/2,1/3,\dots,1/N$?

Comment: The intervals contain those elements and the sum of the lengths are less than ϵ/2 and also they are disjoint. Am I missing something important here?

Comment: I got it now I am sorry I was so careless!